# Need help in scheme program won't know how to create it

Tags: scheme

Write a Scheme function that takes two atoms and a list as parameters and returns a list identical to the parameter list except all occurrences of the first given atom in the list are replaced with the second given atom.

```
(define(swap val1 val2 lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) (lst val1))
          ((equal? val2 lst) (lst))
          (else(equal? val2 (cadr lst)) (swap val1 val2 (cadr lst)))))
```

Comment: This is not a question, it's a request to have homework done. Hints: Use recursion over the structure of the list. You need to consider three cases.

Comment: im trying but wont get succeeded so im confused and hesitated to put code over here. that's what im trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two major syntactical problems is that `(lst val1)` and `(lst)` tries to call `lst` as a function, and that `else` shouldn't have a condition - the `cond` form is

```
(cond (condition1 expression1)
      (condition2 expression2)
      (else       expression))
```

`(equal? val2 lst)` says "`val2` is equal to the entire list `lst`". This does not make sense.

`(equal? val2 (cadr lst))` says "`val2` is equal to the second element of the list `lst`". You don't need to care about the second element.

The first element is `car`. The tail is `cdr`. (Many use `first` and `rest`, which are more modern names.)

You're pretty close to a solution, so I'll just give you a structure:

- If the list is empty, the result is the empty list.
- If the first element of the list is the one you're replacing, `cons` the new value onto the result of recursing on the rest of the list.
- Otherwise, `cons` the existing value onto the result of recursing on the rest of the list.

Comment: Is this right?

*(define(swap val1 val2 lst)

*(cond ((null? lst) null)

*((equal? val2 (car lst)) (cons val1 lst))

(else(swap val1 val2 (cdr lst)))))

Comment: @farrukhali Almost - you forgot the recursion in one place, and a `cons` in another.

Comment: i think its fine ? i did recursion on else condition and cons on 2nd condition

Comment: kindly tell me where should i place recursion and cons again?

Comment: You need both in both places. Like I wrote in the answer.

Comment: i used 2nd condition to stop the recursion. are they won't solve my problem?

Comment: @farrukhali Recursion should stop only when the list is empty, or you won't process all occurrences.